# Lucene search getting strange facet results for a text field

Tags: lucene, sitecore, facet, faceted-search

I'm using Sitecore with Lucene, and I'm trying to facet on an integer field, so that I can get all of the existing values for that field. I have the following search result class with a definition for the field:

```
public class ContentTypeSearchResultItem : Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes.SearchResultItem
{
    [Sitecore.ContentSearch.IndexField("crop_heat_units")]
    public int CropHeatUnits { get; set; }
}
```

in my query, I have

```
query = query.FacetOn.FacetOn(x => x.CropHeatUnits)
```

I have a number of other facets of type `ID` or `IEnumerable<Guid>` and these work as I expect, but the `crop_heat_units` string facet is giving me weird results, such as `chufacet.Values[0].Name = \u0001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\u000e\b`. Some of the other values are `@\b\0\0\0\0` and `8\u0010\0\0\0\0\0`.

In Sitecore, the values of the Crop Heat Units field are things like "2075" and "2200".

Answer (score 0):

Each numeric value is indexed as a **trie** structure within Lucene where each term is logically assigned to larger and larger predefined brackets which are simply lower precision representations of the value.

So, the simple solution is to change `int` to `string` for your *CropHeatUnits* field definition and remove it from the fieldmap. Then your queries and facets should work as expected. If you want to use the *CropHeatUnits* values as integers then you will need to cast their `string` values to `integer` after their retrieval from Lucene.